# How do you tell Xamarin Studio to give verbose output for a build?

Tags: android, ios, mobile, ide, xamarin-studio

I'd like to see all the variables that are usable from the Condition element inside something like:

```
<Reference Include="FSharp.Core" Condition="'$(TargetFrameworkVersion)' == 'v4.0'">
  <HintPath>..\..\lib\FSharp\FSharp.Core.dll</HintPath>
  <Private>True</Private>
</Reference>
```

How do I tell Xamarin Studio to print them out during the build?  I didn't see anything like a "verbose/debug" option in the Options dialog.

(I'm using Xamarin Studio 4.1.9)

Answer (score 2):

Right click on your main project in the solution -> Options.

On the left-hand side, under Build -> iOS Build you see Additional Options -> Additional mtouch arguments.

Enter -v -v -v -v for a verbose log.

PS Since i am writing this a year and a half after the question, I am talking about Xamarin Studio 5.7.1